# Use of lambda in filter query in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, lambda, django-views

In my model I have a column name category and the values are in the form of 
"`x -> y -> z"`
x,y,z all are separated by arrow (->) (although whole itself is a string)

what I want is to filter objects on the basis of 'y' string

something like

```
MyModel.objects.filter(category = lambda key: y in key)
```

but it gives me error  `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

```
Example: MyModel (3 column, category column is foreign key to another model(which has only one column same name=category))
ID   name   category
1    xyz    world->europe->france
2    abc    animal->fourleg->dog
3    pqr    car->europe->benz
```

I applied this below query

`MyModel.objects.filter(category = lambda key: 'europe' in key)`and

And I was expecting two returned objects (Id 1 and 3).

I hope its clear now?

I'm not able to figure it out why this is happening. Or is there any other way to do same thing?
I'm new to django so it may be meaningless/irrelevant or silly question but I'm not able to find the solution.

> Python 2.x
>
> Django 1.4.x

Comment: I'm puzzled by your puzzlement. There is no reason to think this could ever work, and I don't know why you think it would. That's simply not how Django queries work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: so what do you suggest? any other alternative?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you give some examples of instances of your model, your intended query and expected output?

Comment: @desiredlogin : please look at the updated question detail. I've added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your string is structured you might be able to use a `contains` lookup. Something like:

```
# 'name' is whatever your string column on category is called
MyModel.objects.filter(category__name__contains='->{}->'.format(y_string))
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) for more details on lookup types.

Comment: error : `Related Field has invalid lookup: contains`  ?

Comment: @pankaj: You originally said that category was a string. Apparently it's actually a `ForeignKey`? This is why you should always put your models in the question. Regardless, I've updated the answer to match.

Comment: thanks :)
one more thing `category__name__contains='->{}->'.format(y_string))` didn't work but `category__name__contains='y_string')` works well :)